# How to retrieve the couchbase view results using iteration?

Tags: c#, foreach, couchbase

This is my code for retrieving the list of comments from couchbase. The design document name is "Task" and the view name is: "GetComments".

```
public List<CommentsVO> GetComments(string TaskID, int LastCommentID, int totalCommentCount)
        {

            int startCount = LastCommentID - 1;

            int endCount = startCount - 19;
            int remainingCount = totalCommentCount - endCount;
            if (endCount < 0)
            {
                endCount = 0;// totalCommentCount - remainingCount;
            }


            IView<CommentsVO> results = oCouchbase.GetView<CommentsVO>("Task", "GetComments");

           results.StartKey(new object[] { TaskID, startCount }).EndKey(new object[] { TaskID, endCount });

            if (results != null)
            {
                List<CommentsVO> resultlist = new List<CommentsVO>();

                foreach (CommentsVO vo in results)//Here it is not entering inside the loop... Am i missing anything in this condition
                {
                    resultlist.Add(vo);
                }

                resultlist.Reverse();
                return resultlist;
            }

            return null;

        }
```

My CommentsVo code is:

```
public class CommentsVO
    {
        public CommentsVO()
        {
            CommentedOn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
            IsActive = "1";
        }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string TaskID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("commented_user_id")]
        public string CommentedUserID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("commented_user_name")]
        public string CommentedUserName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("comment_description")]
        public string CommentDescription { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("commented_on")]
        public string CommentedOn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("is_active")]
        public string IsActive { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("seq")]
        public string Sequence { get; set; }
    }
```

My couchbase view code is:

```
function(doc) {
    for(var i in doc.comments) {
        emit([doc._id,doc.comments[i].seq],doc.comments[i]);
    }
}
```

I have tried without using startkey and endkey its iterating but when i tried using startkey and endkey it is not entering inside the loop..

Kindly help me out..

Answer (score 0):

When using a composite key, you would specify an array of keys in StartKey/EndKey.  In your code, you're actually overwriting the keys with your second calls to StarKey and EndKey.

So something like:

```
results.StartKey(new object[] { TaskId, startCount }).EndKey(new object[] { TaskId, endCount });
```

Comment: I have edited my code as per u suggested..But now its throwing an exception as "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."